# Cannot create an object of type System.Guid from its string representation error on UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Registration of my user control on .aspx page like this:

```
<uc:MyControl Id="MyControlId" runat="server"></uc:MyControl>
```

And I'm using a method that belongs to this user control on code behind of .aspx page:

```
MyControlId.MyMethod();
```

But I get this error while parsing: **"Cannot create an object of type 'System.Guid' from its string representation 'MyControlId' for the 'Id' property"**. How can I fix this?

Note: This is not the solution I'm looking for: [Cannot create an object of type 'System.Object' from its string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260343/cannot-create-an-object-of-type-system-object-from-its-string-representation)

MyMethod() in user control:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
  BindInfo();
  InfoArea.Style.Add("display", "block");
}
```

Comment: Your starting tag is `uc:MyControl` while your ending tag is `/uc:GeneralInfo` does it even compile?

Comment: Sorry for that. I changed the original code part while asking, just missed out. There is no compilation problem. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Can you show the code of your `MyControl` class?

Comment: I added the code of MyMethod().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the real solution. There was a Guid property named as 'Id' in the interface of my user control. So, the interface member 'Id' conflicts with the Id attribute of the user control. Changing the interface member's name solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the below

```
MyControlId.MyMethod();
```

with

```
MyControl.MyMethod();
```

Comment: I couldn't access the control using tagname.

Comment: you can not call the `MyMethod` by using the id of the user control instead you should use the same user control class name

Comment: @zarathustra import the namespace in your code behind of the userControl

Comment: @zarathustra I don't think that is true. `<uc:MyControl Id="MyControlId" ..></uc:MyControl>` results in a (generated) field of type `MyControl` with name `MyControlId`. So, yes, you do refer to the usercontrol instance as specified by the `Id` tag. If you use the control class name, you are not referring to an instance method, but to a static method.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Using the name of control solved the problem.

Comment: @Maarten If it is static method then we call as i said(generally we write static methods in Usercontrols), if not with object of the class(i.e user control class). Do you know any other methods.